# Javascript: Adding digits without Sum?

Tags: javascript, node.js, time, amazon-ec2

I'm basically trying to get the hours, minutes, and seconds of a date in javascript to read like this: '123456'. I am doing this with the following code:

```
var date;
date = new Date();
var time = date.getUTCHours() + date.getUTCMinutes() + date.getUTCSeconds();
```

Only problem is when I add them together, I keep getting the sum, not a nice line of 6 numbers like I want.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Why are you converting them to numbers (especially since they're already numbers) with the preceding `+` then? Use `var time = "" + date.getUTCHours() + date.getUTCMinutes() + date.getUTCSeconds()";`

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean for that to be in there, I was just trying out different things..I edited my question.

Comment: @Ian - You are correct that it is wrong, but there is no conversion to numbers there. getUTC(Hours|Minutes|Seconds) returns a Number value, not a string.

Comment: Do you want a time like 1:23:05 to show 1235 or 012305? In the 1235 case, use Ian's answer; in the 012305 case, you have to use Geoffrey's second response, since only it pads single digits with zeros.

Comment: @Geoffrey The `+` converts to numbers, so although the values are already numbers (which I mentioned in my comment), it's what it *does* in this type of situation

Comment: I need the end string to always be 6 characters...so i'll go with Geofferey's response. Thanks~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var time = '' + date.getUTCHours() + date.getUTCMinutes() + date.getUTCSeconds();
```

edit:
To account for zero-padding you can do something like:

```
function format(x){
    if (x < 10) return '0' + x;
    return x;
}

var date;
date = new Date();
var time = '' + format(date.getUTCHours()) + format(date.getUTCMinutes()) + format(date.getUTCSeconds());
```

Comment: I actually like this solution better but i can't seem to get the zero padding working. Do I just insert it as you've shown here?

Answer (score 2):

Convert the numerical value to a string:

```
var date;
date = new Date();
var time = date.getUTCHours().toString() + date.getUTCMinutes().toString() + date.getUTCSeconds().toString();
```

If you want it to always be 6 characters long, you need to pad the values if they are < 10. For example:

```
var hours = date.getUTCHours();
if (hours < 10)
     hours = '0' + hours.toString();
else hours = hours.toString();

var mins = date.getUTCMinutes();
if (mins < 10)
     mins = '0' + mins.toString();
else mins = mins.toString();

var secs = date.getUTCSeconds();
if (secs < 10)
     secs = '0' + secs.toString();
else secs = secs.toString();

var time = hours + mins + secs;
```

Comment: That's silly. Just start the concatenation with `var time = "" + date.getUTC...`

Comment: It looks like both solutions work. I do always need it to be 6 characters so i'll implement your changes...thanks again!

Comment: @Ian - You could do it that way if you like, but I am a purist in my coding style and like to write code that is obvious as to it's function. Each to their own.

Answer (score 0):

That's happening because those functions return an Integer type.  If you want to add the digits themself togheter,  try converting every variable to string using toString()